# In Apache Camel, When should one implement Processor?

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have seen some Apache Camel based ActiveMQ listeners with a route class that passes messages to classes that implement Processor interface. In other listeners, the class that processes messages, does not implement Processor. When should one implement Processor?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **only when you are obligated to**.

Whenever possible, **prefer simple [Java Beans with Bean Binding](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html)**. You can automatically inject whatever you need from you message in your Bean method.

For example if you call the following method from your route with a `bean` command, you get the message body as String and the whole Exchange injected.

```
public String doSomething(String body, Exchange exchange)
```

This is kind of magic: the first argument is by default the body, the second is evaluated based on the type `Exchange`.

You can make things more transparent if you use [parameter binding annotations](http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html):

```
public String doSomething(@Body String body, @Header("JMSCorrelationID"))
```

If you begin to implement beans like this, you will almost never implement [`Processor`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Processor.html) again. The **beans are much easier to test and more portable** (you can use them also in another, non-camel context).

However, there are or were some places where a [`Processor`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Processor.html) implementation is/was needed, but these cases were more and more eliminated. I have no idea if some of them still exist, but at least I did not have implemented `Processor` since a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use a class that implement Processor when you need to use different features of current Exchange object i.e properties, message headers etc.
You may use class which does not implement Processor - when you are not dependent on current Exchange object in any way - but intend to invoke a method on a bean.